# Getting Warnings in Unity 5.5 Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity5.5 editor I am getting several warnings of which two include:

[image]

```
Platform LinuxStandaloneSupport has only one supported graphics device type (OpenGL Core)
Platform MacStandaloneSupport does not support graphics device type OpenGL
```

How would I go about solving these errors, as by reading them I have noticed I have to change my graphics device type perhaps but first of all I am not sure if this is the solution and second of all even if it would be I am not entirely sure how I would do so.

Edit:
I am not sure if this is related and able to help you guys out, but I am also receiving errors like:

Assets/Editor/ImageEffects/ColorCorrectionLookupEditor.cs(54,41): warning CS0618: `UnityEditor.TextureImporter.textureFormat' is obsolete:`textureFormat is not longer accessible at the TextureImporter level. For old 'simple' formats use the textureCompression property for the equivalent automatic choice (Uncompressed for TrueColor, Compressed and HQCommpressed for 16 bits). For platform specific formats use the [[PlatformTextureSettings]] API. Using this setter will setup various parameters to match the new automatic system as well possible. Getter will return the last value set.'

Comment: Include the warnings in the text of your question. Questions and answers on SO may have external links in them, but shouldn't rely on them for important content.

Comment: ok sry @Cubic..

Comment: How is this related to c#?

Comment: Because for all I know a possible solution to this could be with code @CamiloTerevinto sry if Im wrong...

Comment: This is not related to C#. It is most likely to be the Shader you specified is not supported by some of the graphic device types.

Comment: ok............-

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Assets/Editor/ImageEffects/ColorCorrectionLookupEditor.cs(54,41):
>   warning CS0618: `UnityEditor.TextureImporter.textureFormat'` is
>   obsolete:textureFormat is not longer accessible at the TextureImporter
>   level. For old 'simple' formats use the textureCompression property
>   for the equivalent automatic choice (Uncompressed for TrueColor,
>   Compressed and HQCommpressed for 16 bits). For platform specific
>   formats use the [[PlatformTextureSettings]] API. Using this setter
>   will setup various parameters to match the new automatic system as
>   well possible. Getter will return the last value set.'

It is simply saying that the [`textureFormat`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureImporter-textureCompression.html) property from the [`TextureImporter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureImporter.html) class is now obsolete/deprecated.

The `ImagEffect` scripts are not yet updated to remove warnings in the new Unity 5.5 version. Although, this should *not* stop them from working.

You should generally ignore these warnings since *you did not write* them and Unity will likely fix them in the future.

**If you still want to fix them before Unity**:

**1**.Open up the `ColorCorrectionLookupEditor.cs` script from *Assets/Editor/ImageEffects*.

On line line 54, replace

```
if (textureImporter.textureFormat != TextureImporterFormat.AutomaticTruecolor)
```

with

```
if (textureImporter.textureCompression != TextureImporterCompression.Uncompressed)
```

**2**.On line line 62, replace

```
textureImporter.textureFormat = TextureImporterFormat.AutomaticTruecolor;
```

with

```
textureImporter.textureCompression = TextureImporterCompression.Uncompressed;
```

**3**.Open `MotionBlur.cs` script from *Assets/Standard Assets/Effects/ImageEffects/Scripts*.

`SystemInfo.supportsRenderTextures` is deprecated.

Delete from line 24 to 28 which is the code below:

```
if (!SystemInfo.supportsRenderTextures)
{
    enabled = false;
    return;
}
```

**4**.Open `PostEffectsBase.cs` script from *Assets/Standard Assets/Effects/ImageEffects/Scripts*

On line 115, replace

```
if (!SystemInfo.supportsImageEffects || !SystemInfo.supportsRenderTextures)
```

with

```
if (!SystemInfo.supportsImageEffects)
```

**This should solve all your Image Effects Warnings.**

As for:

> Platform LinuxStandaloneSupport has only one supported graphics device
>   type (OpenGL Core)

and

> Platform MacStandaloneSupport does not support graphics device type
>   OpenGL

That's a bug. Simply ignore them for now. You can update Unity to see if that's fixed since I don't see the-same error on my side and I don't know your Unity version.